# How to know who started/stopped windows service in .NET

Tags: c#, windows-services

Is the way to check in ServiceBase's void OnStart, void OnStop methods, who initialized action?
I need username to write it into log.

Comment: Did you ever find out your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could take the currently logged on user. (my.user.name)

Or for example use the [Autolog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.autolog.aspx) property. This will automatically write an entry to the event log when a service is started/stopped.

```
Mybase.AutoLog = true
```

I hope this answers your question, otherwise please let me know.

Comment: Setting AutoLog property causes event log entries.
This is not what i really need, because I would like to use my custom logger like log4net.

There is another problem: many users can be loggeg on my server machine. I need to determine who exactly stopped service.